# Share session across multiple sites with YII and core PHP

Tags: php, postgresql, session, yii

I am working on a project where I have games in one AWS instance and website is on another instance, Now we are going to use load balancer so I am finding a way to retain website's session into the games instance, so I stored session into the database, the database is common for both games and website instance, Website is developed with Yii 1 and games with phaser and core PHP.

I successfully stored session into the database and website working fine without any issue, but I don't know how can I retrieve that session in my games instance from database.

This is how my session table look likes [image]

Please guide me how can I get this session in games instance. Please note I am using postgres Sql not MySql.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As an AWS user you can store sessions in their DynamoDB for free(25GB). https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/service_dynamodb-session-handler.html

Comment: Our DevOps guys suggesting us to use PHP solution.

Comment: Yep, this solution for PHP.  This store and init sessions from DB.

Comment: I also have website setup on localhost, so I am looking for a solution that works for both localhost and server, although your provided me a great solution but priority is a centralised mechanism work for both localhost and server.

Comment: May this is good way for you https://www.phpclasses.org/package/10282-PHP-Store-PHP-sessions-in-PostgreSQL-table-using-PDO.html

Comment: Thanks for the link, I will check and get back to you.